# Is it possible to have 802.1Q trunk port on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, trunk

I would like to have multiple vlans on Windows Server 2008 machine. Is there any way how to configure trunk port on Broadcom NetXtreme adapter on this OS ? Thank you.

Comment: Note: There is no vLAN support in Windows (any version). You must use 3rd party utilities. All the good NIC Manufacturers provide their own utilities free, including Broadcom.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [product brief for the NetXtreme card](http://www.broadcom.com/collateral/pb/5705M-PB03-R.pdf), it looks like there's support for up to 64 defined VLANs.  Configuration is done via the [Advanced Control Suite](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/support/ethernet_nic/Broadcom_NetLink-NetXtreme_DTM_306.pdf) (on page 35).  Fundamentally, 802.1q support is implemented before the network traffic gets to the OS.  I've been using 802.1q trunks since the Windows 2000 Server days.

Comment: Yes, using BACS is the way to go.

Comment: +1 He'll need Broadcom's configuration utilities to set it up (or HP's if it's an HP branded NIC).

Comment: Yes, it's HP server. I try to find it on HP site.